# Can we have Bremsstrahlung emission of particles which are heavier than the initial radiating particle?

Tags: particle-physics, radiation

Lets consider a light particle in a high-energy process. Can this light particle radiate "Bremsstrahlung particles" which are heavier than the initial light particle?

In this context I don't refer to the usual Bremsstrahlung emission of photons but to the emission of massive particles such as pions in high-energy processes.

Comment: Wouldn't that break the conservation of energy?

Comment: Actually I suppose theoretically as long as conservation of energy is observed, it would be possible. However I'm not aware of any phenomenon where this occurs in reality

Answer (score 0):

At the LHC (among other places), W bosons, Z bosons, and Higgs particles are produced in proton-proton collisions.

Comment: But that is not Bremsstrahlung...

Comment: Traditionally Bremsstrahlung is photons, which are massless. You mention pion creation, which can happen for e.g. hard electron beams on hydrogen targets, like at JLab.  I guess I'm not clear what features of Bremsstrahlung you're hoping to preserve in a non-EM process?